# Performance evaluation of Web API calls with Database LINQ queries

Tags: c#, database, linq, asp.net-web-api, performance-testing

I have a UI which calls WebAPIs (WebAPI 2.0), Web API are basically LINQ queries (to MS SQL database) and some processing logic for the data. I want to do performance evaluation of the complete flow (click from UI to API, back to UI to display data) upon a huge DB with 30K - 60K records in it.

How can it be done? Let me know the methods/tools used for this.

currently I am tracking time-taken in chrome debug window, which shows the total time for each network call.

Comment: I would start by looking into [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) and studying how to use it. Then, you can leverage that to do the stress testing for you. It's a powerful tool. If you really want to generate load, look into non-gui mode.

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  This is a subject in its own right but here's an approach:

The bits are independent so you break it down.  You measure your LINQ queries without any of the logic or web api stuff getting in the way.  If LINQ is against stored procedures then measure those first.  Then you measure the cost of the logic, then you measure the cost of sending X rows of data using WebAPI.  You should avoid including the cost of actually retrieving the rows from the database so you're checking just the connectivity.  I'd also consider writing a browserless test client (i.e. GETS/POSTS or whatever) to eliminate the browser as a variable.

Now you've got a fairly good picture of where the time gets spent.  You know if you've got DB issues, query issues, network issues or application server issues.

Assuming it all goes well, now add a bunch of instances to your test harness so you're testing concurrent access, load testing and the like.  Often if you get something wrong you can't surface that with a single user so this is important.

Break it down into chunks and have a data set that you can consistently bring back to a known state.

As for tools, it really depends on what you use.  VS comes with a bunch of useful things but there are tons of third party ones too. If you have a dedicated test team this might be part of their setup.   SQL Server has a huge chunk of monitoring capability.  Ask your DBAs.   If you've got to find your own way, just keep in mind that you want to be able to do this by pressing a button, not by setting up a complex environment.